# All UWP Samples freezing at splash screen

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, sample

All of UWP Samples I have tried to compile and run do not work. They always freeze on splash screen and stay like that. And after shutting them down, I can't run them again because it says System is using the .exe process.

Comment: Can you check if the freeze happens if your Anti-Virus-App is disabled?

Comment: Sometimes Avast does it.

Comment: It was caused by Avast, thanks for your help!

Comment: Voting to leave open, as the OP found the solution. Raxume or @ganchito55, I suggest one of you post this an answer. I believe this answer may be useful for others with the same problem.

Comment: Great! @Raxume, since the answer by ganchito55 was wat solved your problem, I suggest you mark it as the accepted answer - this signals to other users that this was what solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to turn off your Anti-Virus?

In my case, Avast sometimes blocks my executable, so I have to disable it.